# Looking for an way to filter strings out of a mixed list and than return only the int

Tags: python-3.x

Hello yes this is for a homework help. I just need some guidance to what I'm doing wrong here.

These are the directions:
Filter integers

- Create a function called filter_int() with input parameter list (list) and
  return value (list of integers)
- Create a for loop that will filter list to only get (int)
- Return list of ints
  -DO NOT USE THE FILTER FUNCTION
- Example:

> > > filter_int(["hello", 5, 5.0, 6, "World", "Yes", 4, 9.0])

[5, 6, 4]

And what I have got so far:

```
def filter_int(list):
    list2 = []
    discard = []
    for i in list:
        if i in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm":
            discard.append(i)
        elif i not in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm":
            list2.append(i)
    return list2
```

I got an error on this one when I ran it. I'm kind of new to python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the error?  Did you search on that error to find out what it means?  That is one way that you learn how to fix errors.  If someone here writes you a fixed version of your program you will not learn as much, and will have a harder time with future work and tests

Comment: 1. list is a keyword, so it can't be used as a variable name. Also, what's up with the string of alphabet? Did you mean `if type(i) == int:`?

Comment: Also, why are you building a discard list?  You only need to build the list of ints

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. I don't know what this error is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use isinstance method

```
for i in list:
    if isinstance(i, int):
        list2.append(i)
```

Comment: This one seems to work for my problem. thanks. I just learned of a new function thanks to you.